# How can you construct an NFA with k+2 states, where k is an arbitrary natural?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

I was asked this question and couldn't come up with an answer?

If I had a language $X = \sum^{*} a \sum^{k}$ where $k$ is an arbitrary natural number (the language where the $k+1$'st to last letter is an $a$. My question is: how can you design the NFA of this language, when you do not know what the value of $k$ is. It might be possible that the NFA changes whenever $k$ changes.

Comment: I think you need to know the value of $k$ to define or recognise this language, and the NFA will depend on $k$. Do you know of an NFA for $\Sigma^*$? Do you know an NFA for $\Sigma^k$?

Comment: What you have here is a parameterized family of languages on $\Sigma$, with $k$ the parameter.  Obviously, you get a different automaton for each value of $k$, but they are all very similar.  The minimal number of states, which is $k+2$, is easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following NFA.

[image]

This NFA accepts exactly the strings $\Sigma^*a\Sigma^k$.